# How to make a loading screen before reteofit gets data from server

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, retrofit2

I am using retrofit to fetch data from the server. On app start, an empty recycler view is shown until data is obtained from the server. What would be the best practice to make a loading screen for this purpose? I tried showing a fragment until it's done, and then removing him and always get the `host has ben destroyed error. I saw some methods for making a start splash screen with a new activity, but that way I will still have to wait until data is set. Since the project is pretty big, I didn't put any code. But will add some code if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ProgressBar as the top view in a layout, make it visible and can make other views `invisible` or `gone` as per your layout design.

And as soon you get your API response from your server either successful or failed just hide the progressbar and show the desired view with relevant data (if successful show the data in your recylerview and if failed show failure view instead of recylerview).

This is a very high level to give you an idea to get started. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I already have an image with rotating animation done, I can use it for this instead of progress bar. But is this the right practice to just hide the view after it is done?

Comment: Yes, that is the best way, you view (ProgressBar or whatever view used for loader) always present is layout you just hide and show as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dialog class which contains your progress image (or whatever you want to show on loading progress) and set it, intialize it in on your Base Activity/Base Fragment class so you can call it across your activities/fragments.

Sample:

In your BaseActivity (or similar) class

```
val loadingDialog: LoadingDialog by lazy(mode = LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
    LoadingDialog(this)
}.......

fun showLoading(isLoading: Boolean) {
    loadingDialog.let {
        if (isLoading && !loadingDialog.isShowing)
            loadingDialog.show()
        else if (loadingDialog.isShowing) {
            loadingDialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
.......
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    loadingDialog.dismiss()
}
```

So in your Activity class, which implements your BaseActivity you just call `showLoading(true)` or `showLoading(false)`